# Параметр при сборки библиотеки "shared lib" - что это значит?

Tags: c++, c, cmake

Подскажите пожалуйста, что значит собрать библиотеку с параметром "shared lib" ?
То есть "разделяемая библиотека" - что и с кем она разделяет ?

Это значит, что библиотека будет динамически подключаемая ? Типа .dll для windows ?

Comment: да, это будет dll или so (для линукса) или dlyn (вроде так) для мака

Comment: Это библиотека разделяется между процессами. т.е. исполняемый код будет присутствовать в оперативной памяти в одном экземпляре.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### TL;DR

Динамическая библиотека - скомпилированный бинарь, который сам по себе не является программой, но предоставляет какие-то функции, которые могут импортировать другие программы во время своей работы. Пример - `sprintf()` из `libc` в *NIX и `ntdll.dll` в Windows.

---

### Про этапы компиляции

Компиляцию программы можно разделить, если грубо, на два этапа: трансляцию и линковку. Первый этап иногда еще называют компиляцией, но у новичков это вызывает путаницу, так что будем придерживаться терминологии, обозначенной выше.

**Трансляция**

В это время транслятор (часть компилятора, которая отвечает за перевод человекочитемого исходника в бинарный вид) парсит даннный на вход файл, проверяет базовый синтаксис и пытается оттранслировать его в бинарный вид. На выходе мы получаем `*.o` или `*.obj` файл, в котором содержится бинарный вид компилируемого исходника. В этот момент мы еще не можем его запустить - в таком виде любой прыжок не в программе не определен. А прыжков, даже в линейной программе, наподобие "Hello world!", хватает - мы так или иначе подключаем библиотеки, чтобы самим с нуля не писать функции для вывода на экран (да и, спойлер, без дергания ядра ОС это все равно невозможно, а чтобы работать с ядром все равно нужны библиотеки).

> Для примера разберем этап трансляции того же Hello world'a:
> Если мы хотм, чтобы компилятор не зашел дальше трансляции, то у GCC существует замечательный ключ `-c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    puts("Hello world!");

    return 0;
}
```

```
$ gcc -c main.o main.c
```

> И посмотрим содержимое обьектного файла с помощью `objdump`:

```
main.o:     file format elf64-x86-64


Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000000000 <main>:
   0:   55                      push   %rbp
   1:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
   4:   48 8d 05 00 00 00 00    lea    0x0(%rip),%rax        # b <main+0xb>
   b:   48 89 c7                mov    %rax,%rdi
   e:   e8 00 00 00 00          call   13 <main+0x13>
  13:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
  18:   5d                      pop    %rbp
  19:   c3                      ret
```

> Как видно, здесь просто наша функция main, которая оттранслирована в асм. Причем `call` идет на `00 00 00 00` - то есть по нулевому смещению, о чем нам `objdump` сообщает, показывая, что прыжок будет на `<main+13>`, то есть следующую строчку. По понятным причинам, такой файл не является исполняемым.

**Линковка**

Это момент, когда следующая часть компилятора, под названием линковщик, берет оттраслированный обьектный файл и вычисляет куда и как он должен прыгать, то есть, фактически, делает возможным его исполнение. На этом же этапе появляется возможность подгружать функции из динамических библиотек. Но об этом ниже.

> Продолжим мучить Hello world. На прошлом этапе мы получили обьектный файл, в котором не посчитаны адреса. Что ж, теперь посчитаем адреса и получим исполняемый файл:

```
$ gcc -o main main.o
```

> (Я не буду прикладывать весь вывод `objdump`'a, потому что он реально огромен, а просто приложу еще раз функцию main). Остальные функции являются служебными и служат для запуска программы/использования функций из динамических библиотек

```
0000000000001139 <main>:
    1139:       55                      push   %rbp
    113a:       48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
    113d:       48 8d 05 c0 0e 00 00    lea    0xec0(%rip),%rax        # 2004 <_IO_stdin_used+0x4>
    1144:       48 89 c7                mov    %rax,%rdi
    1147:       e8 e4 fe ff ff          call   1030 <puts@plt>
    114c:       b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
    1151:       5d                      pop    %rbp
    1152:       c3                      ret
    1153:       66 2e 0f 1f 84 00 00    cs nopw 0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
    115a:       00 00 00
    115d:       0f 1f 00                nopl   (%rax)
```

> Как мы видим, здесь у `call`'a появился адрес, теперь мы прыгаем не "вникуда", а куда-то, где определена функция `puts` (на самом деле, это тоже не совсем так, но об этом опять-таки ниже).

---

### Немного про библиотеки в целом

Для начала немного о терминологии. Очень много раз видел, как хедеры (`*.h` файлы) называют библиотеками. Это не совсем корректно. По-хорошему говоря, в хедере (если он написан правильно) нет определений функций - только их обьявления. А вот сами функции уже лежат в библиотеке, хедер нужен исключительно для того, чтобы корректно вызывать функции в программе.

**Статические библиотеки**

Первый тип библиотек - статические. Это означает, что во время линковки библиотека жестко оказывается вшита внутрь бинарника. По сути, статическая библиотека является архивом с обьектными файлами, которые содержат реализации функций из хедера. То есть, когда мы создаем статическую библиотеку, то вместо вызова линковщика после трансляции мы собираем все хедеры в один архив и предоставляем это конечному пользователю как библиотеку.

> Рассмотрим пример (опять будут *NIX):
> У нас есть два хедера с соответствующими `*.c` файлами и `main.c`, который эти хедеры использует. Соберем из всего этого добра статическую библиотеку и попытаемся получить полноценную программу:

```
#ifndef BYE_H
#define BYE_H

void print_bye(void);

#endif
```

```
#include "bye.h"

#include <stdio.h>

void print_bye()
{
    puts("Bye world!");
}
```

```
#ifndef PRINT_H
#define PRINT_H

void print_hello(void);

#endif
```

```
#include "hello.h"

#include <stdio.h>

void print_hello(void)
{
    puts("Hello world!");
}
```

```
#include "hello.h"
#include "bye.h"

int main(void)
{
    print_hello();
    print_bye();

    return 0;
}
```

> Собираем хедеры, как мы уже умеем:

```
$ gcc -c hello.c bye.c
```

> Получаем два обьектных файла. Теперь нужно их собрать в архив с помощью `ar`. Тут небольшое отступление про нейминг - есть договоренность, что имена библиотек должны начинаться с `lib`. И линковщик при указании бибилотеки, как мы увидим далее, пытается найти файл начинающийся именно с `lib`. Поэтому создадим библиотеку `print`, с названием файла `libprint.a`:

```
$ ar rc libprint.a hello.o bye.o
```

> Следующий этап - добавление индекса символов к библиотеке, чтобы линковщик смог понять, какие функции/переменные/етц есть, а каких нет. Вообще, в большинстве случаев `ar` добавляет такой индекс сам, но есть ситуации, когда он этого не делает. Поэтому хорошим тоном считается добавлять его руками, даже если это ничего не изменит:

```
$ ranlib libprint.a
```

> После чего мы получили статическую библиотеку, которая при линковке окажется жестко зашита в бинарник. Посмотрим, что это означает. Скомпилируем с этой библиотекой и откроем через `objdump` (обратите внимание, что название библиотеки мы указываем без префикса `lib`, линковщик сам его добавит:

```
$ gcc main.c -L. -lprint -o main
$ objdump -d main
```

```
0000000000001139 <main>:
    1139:       55                      push   rbp
    113a:       48 89 e5                mov    rbp,rsp
    113d:       e8 22 00 00 00          call   1164 <print_hello>
    1142:       e8 07 00 00 00          call   114e <print_bye>
    1147:       b8 00 00 00 00          mov    eax,0x0
    114c:       5d                      pop    rbp
    114d:       c3                      ret

000000000000114e <print_bye>:
    114e:       55                      push   rbp
    114f:       48 89 e5                mov    rbp,rsp
    1152:       48 8d 05 ab 0e 00 00    lea    rax,[rip+0xeab]        # 2004 <_IO_stdin_used+0x4>
    1159:       48 89 c7                mov    rdi,rax
    115c:       e8 cf fe ff ff          call   1030 <puts@plt>
    1161:       90                      nop
    1162:       5d                      pop    rbp
    1163:       c3                      ret

0000000000001164 <print_hello>:
    1164:       55                      push   rbp
    1165:       48 89 e5                mov    rbp,rsp
    1168:       48 8d 05 a0 0e 00 00    lea    rax,[rip+0xea0]        # 200f <_IO_stdin_used+0xf>
    116f:       48 89 c7                mov    rdi,rax
    1172:       e8 b9 fe ff ff          call   1030 <puts@plt>
    1177:       90                      nop
    1178:       5d                      pop    rbp
    1179:       c3                      ret
    117a:       66 0f 1f 44 00 00       nop    WORD PTR [rax+rax*1+0x0]
```

> Как мы можем видеть, наши функции оказались в бинарнике. Это и есть статическая библиотека - все функции оказываются внутри. Плюсы такого подхода - невозможно использовать подмены библиотек, один файл, что проще распространять и так далее. Минусы - огромный вес файла-результата. Поэтому существует второй подход.

**Динамические библиотеки**

Далее, что же такое динамические (они же разделяемые, хотя этот перевод очень кривой и, его, по-хорошему, стоит избегать) библиотеки. Глобальное их отличие от статических - они не оказываются внутри бинарника, а лежат где-то в системе, но при запуске программы оказываются в ее памяти благодаря механизму отображения файлов (подробнее про это можно почитать [вот тут](https://habr.com/ru/post/55716/)).

> *Лирическое отступление.* Динамические библиотеки называются иногда разделяемыми как раз благодаря вот этому механизму. Потмоу что, по сути, файл физически на диске один. Отсюда и название в Linux/UNIX `Shared Object` (`*.so`). Но по-русски проще и понятнее для окружающих говорить "динамические библиотеки". Тем более, что в Windows и OS X они называются `Dynamic Linked Library` (`*.dll`) и `Dynamic Library` (`*.dylib`) соответственно.

> Пересоберем написанный выше код в динамическую библиотеку и так же попытаемся получить исполняемый файл. В этот раз, нам придется собирать обьектные файлы в виде Position Independent Code - у нас ведь цель, чтобы код работал одинаково в разных участках памяти. Поэтому теперь сборка обьектного файла будет выглядеть как-то так:

```
$ gcc -c -fPIC bye.c hello.c
```

> После этого мы получаем два обьектных файла, которые могут быть собраны в `*.so`. Самое время приступить:

```
$ gcc -shared -o libprint.so bye.o hello.o
```

> На выходе мы получаем динамическую библиотеку `libprint.so`, которая, на самом деле, тоже использует динамическую библиотеку! Ведь функция `puts()`, на самом деле, предоставляется библиотекой `libc.so`. Соберем бинарник:

```
$ gcc main.c -L. -lprint -o main
```

> И попробуем запустить:

```
./main
```

> Неожиданный вывод:

```
./main: error while loading shared libraries: libprint.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

> Дело в том, что система ищет динамические библиотеки по заранее указанному пути, а наша библиотека лежит рядом с бинарником, поэтому система и не может ее найти. Для того, чтобы добавить свой путь поиска необходимо использовать переменную окружения `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, в которой нужно указать директорию с динамической библиотекой. Попробуем еще раз:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=. ./main
```

> В этот раз все хорошо, библиотека подгрузилась и мы увидели две заветные строчки вывода нашей программы.
> Если мы посмотрим на бинарник в `objdump`, то увидим, что функции `print_hello` и `print_bye` находтся в секции `plt`, которая описывает, как вызвать функции из динамических библиотек. Если вам интересна эта тема и как работают таблицы `PLT`, `GOT` и вообще динамическая загрузка - советую погуглить на эту тему, материала много и разобраться достаточно легко.

**UPD.** Чуть не забыл - существует второй способ работы с динамическими библиотеками, чтобы каждый раз не указывать `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. Можно жестко вшить путь библиотеки в сам бинарь, но это чревато последствиями. Делается это с помощью `rpath`:

```
$ gcc {*.c} -L{путь_до_библиотеки} -l{имя_библиотеки} -rpath={путь до библиотеки} -o {имя выходного файла}
```

**UPD2.** В некоторых ситуациях возникает необходимость загрузить свою библиотеку вместо системной - к примеру, своя реализация функции `rand()`. Это делается с помощью `LD_PRELOAD`. Возьмем, для примера, следующий код:

```
#ifndef RAND_H
#define RAND_H

int rand(void);

#endif
```

```
#include "rand.h"

int rand(void)
{
    return 42;
}
```

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
    srand (time(NULL));

    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        printf ("%d\n", rand() % 100);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Если собрать отдельно динамическую библиотеку и отдельно бинарь, то все будет как обычно - даже если указать библиотеку в `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`:

```
$ ./main
74
59
1
47
11
```

```
$ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=. ./main
88
21
88
79
9
```

Но стоит только определить `LD_PRELOAD` как происходит магия и мы получаем ответ на главный вопрос вселенной:

```
$ LD_PRELOAD=./ld_rand.so ./main
42
42
42
42
42
```

Если хотите немного про это почитать, то [вот](https://habr.com/ru/post/479858/) неплохая точка входа

Comment: @AnyKeyShik, Спасибо за такой подробный ответ! К сожалению знаний не хватаем у меня, что бы в полной мере его оценить, но, если Вы говорили, что после транслятора, который "парсит" человечный код в код ассемблера, то почему в получившемся объектном файле нет упоминания массива/строки с "Heelo World" ?

Comment: @AnyKeyShik, но ведь язык С/С++ - не запрещает писать реализацию/определения функция в хедер файлах ? Почему же тогда - это Неправильно ? Все что разрешено языком и все, что компилируется - это значит же Правильно ? Правильно ? :)

Comment: Отвечу по кускам. Для начала, первый вопрос - строка никуда не делась. Видите кусок `lea    0x0(%rip),%rax`? Это загрузка адреса строки в регистр, а после вызов puts, который будет искать адрес строки для вывода в этом регистре

Comment: Второй вопрос. Как пример - на си можно написать программу, которая скомпилируется и будет размером всего в 4 байта. Можете попробовать. Программа просто `main;`. Больше ничего. Кмопилятор прекрасно ее компилирует, только жалуется, что тип не определен. Так что можно скомпилировать не всегда == правильно. Разделение определния и обьявления, как правило, происходит для читабельности кода и возможности создания библиотек. Потому что зачем при инклуде хедера притаскивать с собой еще и определния? Проще оставить эту работу на линкер. По поводу инклуда - советую почитать, что это и как работает